# Modal window doesn’t seem to be working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, materialize

Tried integrating the modal window here on the Lyric button: https://soundwhore.com/trance/tenishia-feat-adina-butar-dont-let-go/

However, nothing happens on click. Any idea, why this would not work?

Code here:

```
<p class="meta-data">
  <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large red" href="#modal-lyric">
    <i class="material-icons left">subject</i>Lyrics
  </a>
  <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large amber accent-4" href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/dont-let-go-feat.-adina-butar/id1054325261?i=1054325265" target="_blank" title="Go to https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/dont-let-go-feat.-adina-butar/id1054325261?i=1054325265">
    <i class="material-icons left">shopping_cart</i>Buy now
  </a>
</p>
<div class="modal" id="modal-lyric">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Lyrics</h4>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat" href="#!">Done</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Source: http://materializecss.com/modals.html

Comment: Can you add the `html code snippet` for your `modal`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just forgot to add the listener:

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".modal").modal()
    });
  </script>
```